# Is is possible to have 2 methods with same name in WebAPI and same Parameter Type?

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api

Is it possible to have 2 methods name with same name in WebApi and same parameter type but different parameter?

For example one is get Product by Yearid

And the other one is  get Product by Productid

And I like to have this Rout:

```
Products?yearId=10
Products/15
```

I know I can have different name but my boss likes to have same name I wonder if it is possible.

and these are methods:

```
    [HttpGet]
    [Route("Products/{yearId}")]
    public async Task<IEnumerable<Make>> GetProductsYearId(int yearId)
    {
        ....
    }

    [HttpGet]
    [Route("Products/{makeid}")]
    public async Task<Make> GetProductById(int makeid) 
    {
         .....      
    }
```

Not sure how the [Route] should looks like to get this end result.

Comment: I'd look at using two different routes: `products/make/{makeid}` and `products/year/{yearid}`

Answer (score 2):

As Brendan Green commented, you would need to have two separate routes defined. Otherwise there wouldn't be a way to determine which method you actually intended to invoke:

```
[HttpGet]
[Route("Products/Year/{yearId}")]
public async Task<IEnumerable<Make>> GetProductsYearId(int yearId)
{
    ...
}

[HttpGet]
[Route("Products/Make/{makeid}")]
public async Task<Make> GetProductById(int makeid) 
{
     ... 
}
```